# Error using seq in data.table r

Tags: r, data.table, seq

I have a data.table like this:

```
DT <- data.table(year = rep(2009,24), id = rep(123,24), cant = c(rep(29,4),rep(30,12),rep(31,8)),
             monthr = c(seq(1,4,1),seq(1,12,1),seq(1,8,1)), count = c(rep(4,4),rep(12,12),rep(8,8)))
```

I want to compute a new var called pond using `seq` as follows:

```
DT[ , pond := ifelse(test = count < 12 && year == 2009,
                             yes = seq(12 - count + 1, 12, 1),
                             no = seq_along(cant)),by = c("id","cant")]
```

But I get the following error:

```
#Error in seq.default(12 - count + 1, 12, 1) : 'from' must be of length 1
```

I suppose that the error comes from the use name of vars in `seq`, but I don't known how to solve it. What can I do?

Comment: Inside the `ifelse`, don't use `=`, also `ifelse` should return the same length.  Perhaps you need `if/else`.  Do you want a 'yes', 'no', label or numeric sequence as output?  Please show the expected output as it is not clear from the code

Comment: I want a numeric sequence as output

Comment: Is this based on `all` the 'count' are less than 12 for the grouping variable or not.  Also the `seq` output can have a different length than the original number of rows, so assigning `:=` will not work

Comment: It is not based in all the count, I want to compute pond to rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the OP's example, 'count' is `unique` for each 'id', 'cant' group, so after grouping by 'id' and 'cant', specify the logical condition for 'year' in `i`, `if` the first value of 'count' is less than 12, get the sequence as showed in the OP's post or `else` return the sequence of rows, assign (`:=`) the output to 'pond'

```
DT[year == 2009, pond := if(count[1] < 12) as.integer(seq(12-count[1] +1, 12, 1))
                    else seq_len(.N), .(id, cant)]
```